# Bash scripts getting permission denied

Tags: bash, sh, sudo

This problem has been a thorn in my side for months and I cant find a solution or a reason behind this. I work with bash scripts a lot and I find that half the time when i execute a .sh script that calls another .sh script, I'll get permission denied during certain sequences of the execution. Sometimes on cp, mkdir, git commands, and sometimes it can execute just fine. If I prepend sudo they work, but my coworker runs the same scripts and never has these issues. So what am I missing?

Another use case:
running command "sudo npm install go-npm",an error code pops up:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/brockwood/spawn-sync.git /home/epoauto/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d4bf86cc
npm ERR! /home/epoauto/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d4bf86cc/.git: Permission denied
```

I've given sudo permissions with 'sudo visudo' but no luck.

Please help!

Comment: You mentioned a co-worker: have you checked the group permissions on all scripts? Are you both trying to execute scripts in `/home/epoauto`?

Comment: We have cloned linux VMs. He set his up 3 months before me and cant remember anything differently from when I set mine up. As for group permissions, I can fix the problem by changing permissions on all scripts, but things like my stated use case can't be fixed that way.